# Insert data with loops

Tags: mysql, loops, row, fill

I have a table with **MySQL** and I would like to insert rows (100 rows more or less) with data.

This is an example table:

**Id | Name | Last Name | Country | Address | Mail | Phone**

I want to fill with a loop and index for example:

**0** | name**0** | lastName**0** | country**0** | address**0** | mail**0**@mail.com | 00000**0**

Where the **number** is the **index** like a loop for.

Should I do it programming it with Java, C# etc? 
Or Can I do it with a query?

Comment: You can do it in pure Mysql but you need a procedure

Answer (score 0):

PHP

Modify vars so this will work for you.

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db('DATABSE_HERE');
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `name`, `last_name`, `country`, `address`, `mail`, `phone`) VALUES ('$i','name$i', 'lastName$i', 'country$i','address$i','mail$i@mail.com','00000$i')");
}
?>
```